# Problem while fetchind data afrom api axios Vue.js "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, Function, got Object"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

So I'm trying to fetch data from api at start of the page which coming in json but when I initialize it in created() or mounted() I get error in chrome console
[chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4g4j.png)

BTable is from the Bootstrap Vue plugin.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            fields: [ ... etc.
.
.
.
.
.


 async created() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4040/invoices')

            this.items = res.data
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    },
```

I declared items as array cause I want to store records there as objects.

Comment: if `res.data` is not an Array, then you can't do that

Comment: `rest.data` is not an `array` check the endpoint data first (means is it object or an array) and take an action for that.

Comment: Yes, I added [] to my json and now it works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Simple yet easy to make mistake